My contract in not deploying
Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/EddiePumpin/My-Hotel
$ yarn hardhat deploy
yarn run v1.22.22
$ "C:\Users\HP FOLIO\.vscode\My-Hotel\node_modules\.bin\hardhat" deploy
Nothing to compile
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing C:\Users\HP FOLIO\.vscode\My-Hotel\deploy\Hotel-Token-deploy.js:
TypeError: network.provider.getSignerFrom is not a function
at getFrom (C:\Users\HP FOLIO\.vscode\My-Hotel\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\helpers.ts:1708:28)


check that hardhat and hardhat-deploy are compatible versions.

"hardhat": "^2.22.13",
"hardhat-deploy": "^0.12.4",
I don't know to check if they are compatible
